# MYSQL select count relational division

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-division

I have this table in mysql
[image]
 1. Is it possible to select a count of - ALL same entity_id where field_tags_tid=2 and field_tags_tid=7

in this example the result would be 1 because only entity_id=6 matches field_tags_tid=2 and field_tags_tid=7

Comment: this picture is actually the result from `SELECT * FROM field_data_field_tags WHERE field_tags_tid=7 OR field_tags_tid=2 ` (note field_tags_tid contain other numbers not just 2 and 7)

Comment: i am not aware of any command that would help me do this....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is often called `Relational Division`

```
SELECT  entity_ID
FROM    tableName
WHERE   field_tags_ID IN (2,7)
GROUP   BY entity_ID
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2
```

if uniqueness was not enforce on `field_tags_ID` for every `entity_ID` then a `DISTINCT` keyword is needed. otherwise, leave it as is,

```
SELECT  entity_ID
FROM    tableName
WHERE   field_tags_ID IN (2,7)
GROUP   BY entity_ID
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT field_tags_ID) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b42da/2)
- [SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) totalCOunt
FROM
(
    SELECT  entity_ID
    FROM    tableName
    WHERE   field_tags_tid IN (2,7)
    GROUP   BY entity_ID
    HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT field_tags_tid) = 2
) s
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b42da/8)

Comment: i tryed the sql fiddle - the result in this case must be 1, because only entity_id=6 matches both 2 and 7 on field_tags_id

Comment: yes!, so how should i call my question title.. to help other people looking for this?

Comment: i updated the answer. uhmm something like relational division :D